# Eclipse - window builder distribution license

Tags: eclipse

I planning to use eclipse as my software to complete my java learning and project. I also planning to handle freelancer project by using eclipse as the coding software. 
I understand that eclipse is free and I have gone through the term and condition - Eclipse Public License (EPL)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_Public_License

As far as I know it is free to distribute my project using eclipse.

However, I planning using eclipse plugin - window builder, will this affect me when I wish to distribute my project for business purposes?

If it is off topic, remind me and I will close this question ASAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When putting a product in production, it should not matter what tools / plugins you use. These license you talk about mainly deal with modifying and distributing the IDE or plugin itself. You don't need to pay royalties or anything else because you used their plugin to develop with.

Comment: Thanks James, I guess now I can start fully focus completing my project without worrying license problem.